# Render Image in MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a field of multiple choices, where you can choose, cat, bird, dog, cat, and you can choose more than one, so everything perfect. I wanted the image of the animal next to the field to appear, so that when I saved the form, when I showed the profile, the image of the chosen animal or of the chosen ones was shown.

forms.py

```
  from django.forms import ModelForm
  from django import forms
  from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple
  from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from PIL import Image
  from django import forms
  from django.core.files import File


   from .models import (
      Usuario,
      Negocio
   )

   PET_CHOICES = (
      ('dog','Cachorro'), 
      ('cat','https://www.petz.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/gato02-303x228.jpg'), 
      ('bird', 'Pássaros'), ('fish','Peixes'),
      ('rep','Reptéis'), ('horse','Cavalos'), ('rat','Roedores')
   )

   class UsuarioForm(UserCreationForm):


          pet = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                 widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=PET_CHOICES)
```

Comment: You mean you want to show the image "after" saving form?

Comment: hello my friend, it can only be later then yes or before and after, which is easier, but my priority is to show the image when the user enters your profile, showing the pets he has selected

Answer (score 0):

Then you don't have to work with form.

You just show pet image from user's instance when enter profile page.

Like this (if `user` is context for user instance)

In `profile.html`

```
<!-- Maybe you just make simple get_pet_url for user pet's image url -->
{{ user.get_pet_url }}
```

ps. If you upload your user model, profile page's template or view, it will more helpful.

### ADD

You can make easier if you use static file. Like this.

```py
# your models.py

MY_PET_IMAGE_URL_CHOICES = {
    # this variate per your pet choices
    {'CAT': 'static/cat_url...'},
    ...
}

class YourUserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    pet_field = ...
    ...

    def get_pet_url(self):
        # You can make what you want. I just use dict for example
        url = MY_PET_IMAGE_URL_CHOICES[self.pet_fieid]
        return url
```

Comment: but how would that look in my models.py?

Comment: What do you mean look in my models.py? You mean how to make `get_pet_url` method?

Comment: and if instead of URL I use static files

Comment: Yes, How to makes get